# Setting base font size to 17px: Should it be done on body or on paragraph, accessibility wise?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, font-size

I found a nice font for my webpage, but at the default `16px` (= `1em`) size its a bit too small imo, so I want to set the body font size a bit larger, at `17px`.

Is it alright to do this on the `body` element or should I instead set the font size for all paragraphs to `1.0625em`, which is `17px` calculated on a `16px` base size? What is better for accessibility?

Comment: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/

Comment: @cimmanon Funny you post that article, because thats exactly why I am asking. Normally I just follow that advice because it seems to be a good idea, but in that case the font just looks too tiny for my eyes and I don't think one can assume the user uses text-zoom.

Comment: You've got a chicken vs egg scenario here.  Most "designers" (browser makers, too; Nielsen laments about that here:  http://www.nngroup.com/articles/let-users-control-font-size/) have lost sight of what's good for the user to the point where the user can't even have the font-size they genuinely want anymore (don't like 12px font? too bad, I am scaling all of my text around that anyway).  My co-worker had to set his minimum font-size to something like 16-18px to ensure he can always read the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t assume that the "base size" is 16px. While it may be the default for most desktop web browsers, users can change this value.

If your question is `body` vs. `p`, note that there are usually other elements than `p` that may contain text that should often be in the same size. For example `li`, `dt`, `dd`, or `div` for lines that are not suitable for `p`, form elements like `input`, etc.

The nicest way for your visitors would be to set the main content’s (i.e., the text body) font size  to `1em` (resp. `font-size:medium;` resp. `font-size:100%;`), as this is the font size that users might have set up in their browser deliberately. Of course it should be no problem to go a little bit higher or lower from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Setting the font size to `1em` or `100%` would equal the size the user has set in the (maybe custom) UA stylesheet, right? So how could I "go a littler higher", simply by setting the body font-size to `1.0625em`? (Of course its possible that its not `17px`anymore, but the relations would be the same)?

Comment: @Sven: Correct, yes. You could take a higher `em`/`%` value, or use the `larger` keyword, or go to the next step with the `large` keyword (which might probably be a too large step).

Answer (score 2):

Neither option is better or worse for accessibility.

Desktop browsers generally do default to 16px for 1em, and it is *possible* for users to change this on some systems. However, zoom is the default 'make things bigger' control on desktop browsers (IE, Firefox, Safari, Opera and Chrome). Zoom makes everything bigger, in proportion, not just text. (See also [why zoom is good for accessibility](http://alastairc.ac/2013/08/browser-zoom-great-for-accessibility/).)

Therefore setting a size for body or paragraph is really a question about managing styles, rather than accessibility.

Setting body text size to 1em:

```
body {font-size: 1em;}
p {font-size: 1em; } /* 16px */
```

Is actually doing nothing, as it was 1em by default. If it wasn't 16px because the user changed it, you have no idea what it is.

Setting body to `17px` will slightly increase the font size *if* other styles use a relative unit:

```
body {font-size: 20px;}
p {font-size: 1em; } /* 20px */
```

This is useful if you want to make all the text relative to one value.
NB: using [`rem`](http://caniuse.com/#search=rem) as the unit would be even better if you don't have to worry about IE<9.

For users who do manage to set a different default font-size, that should over-ride the body style and increase things in proportion, regardless of which option you use. The only things to be aware of is setting a large default *relative* size:

```
/* bad example for people who adjust their text size to 20px */
body {font-size: 150%;}
h2 {font-size: 2em; } /* 60px */
```

I have come across a situation like that where people who changed their default text-size were complaining how big the text was!

I tend to set the body to `16px` and then use `rem` for all text sizing styles. Users can zoom or adjust size, and things work proportionally.